# Area Calculation of object in semantic segmentation model's output image

Tags: python

I would like to know the logic of calculating irregular polygon object area, which gets detected based on Semantic segmentation model. I got binary mapping of my object as output. Resolution used is 5M.
Kindly help me on calculating area for this detected object in Python.
Thank you

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Where exactly are you stuck codewise?

Comment: Object detected in the output of Semantic segmentation is irregular polygon, so just curious to know , whether there is any mechanism to calculate area for irregular polygon in python.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the shapely library does what you want:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
polygon = Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)])
polygon.area
```

[link](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html)

Edit: You need to get the coordinates of your object, maybe that is your real question? Please by specific so we don't have to guess what yor asking.